# Deadlock while updating SQL Server 2008 table though multitasking

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server with this schema:

```
RunJob Table 
(
    id identity,
    SqlCode nvarchar(max)   -- store dynamic sql which will be executed by SP.
    Start_time              -- will be null at the start,  will be updated at the start of SqlCode column's dynamic sql execution
    EndTime                 -- end time of SqlCode dynamic sql execution 
    Status char(2)          -- initially it will be NS(no started), IP (in progress while execution of SqlCode) , CO or FA ( completed or failed at the end)
)
```

Table has around 25000 rows. I am using C# multi tasking program to call one SQL Server stored procedure from 4 threads.

So the same stored procedure will be called 4 times concurrently. This stored procedure has a while loop and picks up the max ID where Startime is null and status is NS (not started).

For that row, the stored procedure will set startdate, staus to IP, take the text from `SqlCode` column and execute it, and at the end, it will update the `Endtime` and `status` to `Co\FA`.

In the stored procedure, while reading the data, I use no lock and while updating I use rowlock.

But I'm still getting deadlocks while updating my `RunJob` table.

Can anyone suggest what else I can do to avoid deadlocks?

One more point - after using transaction level read uncommitted, I am getting fewer deadlocks. ^

Comment: Any reason you are reading uncommitted data and not committed only? a little more background on the transaction would be helpful

Comment: Seeing the SP code will really help.

Comment: @jimmy8ball - i tried both committed and uncommitted ... its just my observation that i am getting less deadlocks while using read uncommitted

Comment: You should update your question with the deadlock graph. Not as a picture, as xml

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when working with concurrent scenarios you are describing you'd probably be best off using **sp_getapplock** (followed by sp_releaseapplock) on a very granular level.
Andy Novick explains this very well in this article:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3202/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-the-same-sql-server-stored-procedure-at-the-same-time/

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to spread the workload to those 4 threads, evenly. Then you can consider using NTILE(4) over(cols) to get you thread_numbers.

So the WHILE loop can be avoided which does the MAX(id) logic, if that is the point of causing deadlocks.

It would be a better to understand what is going on in the stored procedure to suggest other alternatives

Comment: I used the same logic earlier... however rejected by client architect..because it will not be the optimum use of every thread. In my case Each thread is running dynamic SQL stored in one column.. so it may possible first bucket of NTILE will get all the big time taking queries whereas last  thread will get smaller quires and finish early..

Comment: With the current design, of max+1 how is the ranking of dynamic SQL column queries done. If there is a ranking which is done, you could use the same logic and order by -->NTILE() OVER(Order by <evenly_spread_query_execution_time>)